# How to design a database schema to store comments for some parts of an article?

Tags: database-design

I'm planning to design a blogging system and I want to implement a feature to let the user comment on parts of an article. The feature should look like this.

[image]

The problem is that, the article could be very long and users can select any part of it and comment. How could I identify which part of the article a comment is for? What's the proper way to design the database schema for this case?

Comment: I would work with indices: At which index does the comment start and end. How you get the indices depends on the programming language you use and can be more complicated.

Comment: I think it's not an easy task to find the indexes. When the user are actually commenting, the information has already been displayed on the web. The user simply make a selection, but we need to pass the text of the selection to the server and find the indexes. What if the selection appeared multiple times in the article?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple solution to the problem with the indices. When you are using javascript you can use the following Code:

```
function logIndicesOfSelectedText() {
    //log the start index
    console.log(window.getSelection().anchorOffset);
    //log the end index    
    console.log(window.getSelection().focusOffset);
    //log the selected text
    console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
}

document.onmouseup = getIndicesOfSelectedText;
```

This just prints the indices and the selected text to the console, but working with them should be an easy task.